# Windows 8 24x24 badge logo image failing wac tool test

Tags: windows-8

I am developing windows 8 app using tool **Microsoft Visual Studio Express for Windows 8**
When I am creating app packages to upload on app store it fails the WAC tool test and gives out following error.

```
Image reference "images\badge_24.png": The image "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps
\myproject\images\badge_24.png" has an ABGR value "0x1D5E50E9" at position (9, 0) 
that is not valid. The pixel must be white (##FFFFFF) or transparent (00######).
```

I searched on net and found the link [Badge Issue in VS update 1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2792380#survey)

I am not using 34x34 image for badge logo. I am using 24x24 image still I am getting the error by wac tool due which **I can not submit this to App Store.**

I tried with using 34x34 image but its not working can any one help me with this?

Comment: try changing the ABGR value at position (9, 0) to ##FFFFFF? or 00######?

Comment: (9,0) is (x,y) am I right? Have to visited the link Badge Issue in VS update 1?

Comment: @JosephH I did it but its not working gives the same error with (9,2) position

Comment: Have you tried my suggestions in the answer below?

Comment: Hi I tried your steps below and it worked.Thanks.

Comment: Nice:) I remember it cost me some valuable time in the stressful release period so I am happy I can share. Good luck with your release!

Comment: Hello...,If i fallowing your process image is showing white space..my image placed at https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=143242B617BA6BE2!9001&authkey=!AGgZPS0JGUYWO0M&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know this problem very well. It is not related to the image size but to the image content. The error message is actually very precise - not all pixels in your badge logo fulfill the requirement that they are fully white ##FFFFFF or transparent 00######.

I suggest your first step is a confirmation that my answer is right. For that purpose just create a temporary 24x24 image which would be completely white. If you use this temp white logo the WAC should pass.

Next step would be to get a proper logo image. I did the following with GIMP graphic tool (http://www.gimp.org/downloads/):

1. Identify background color of your logo, navigate to Colors > Color to alpha and select the identified color. That makes your background transparent.
2. Now it's time to desaturate the whole picture by Colors > Desaturate
3. Restrict bits to ##FFFFFF and 00###### only: Navigate to Colors > Brightness-Contrast and set both Brightness and Contrast to the max values.

To be sure, I am right you might want to attach your current badge logo to your original question.

Comment: my image placed at https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=143242B617BA6BE2!9001&authkey=!AGgZPS0JGUYWO0M&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Comment: Hello, this answer is 4 years old. I do not even have the developer environment installed for it. I remember however 100% this was the fix and also the fact it got 11 upvotes and the comment on the original question proves this helped number of developers to solve the problem - that it worked for them. Either you did not follow exactly or something has changed after 4 years - this is the only explanation I can come up with atm. Best regards, Jan

Answer (score 1):

The solution is really simple! Just import your badge logo into Adode Photoshop and Press [Control + L] or Go to the menu [Image> Adjustments> Levels] and set the values as:

Channel: RGB
Input Levels up fields: 253; 1,00; 255
Input Levels down fields: 255; 255

Save your image!

Afterward, just redo do process of creating App Packages on visual Studio. Now Enjoy you app approved!

Answer (score 0):

One way to automate the process is to write a litte C# console application that "fixes" the images:

Add a nuget reference to package Magick.NET.Core-Q8
Perform the following code to remove < 255 color channels:

```
foreach( string ThisFile in Directory.GetFiles( @"C:\YourUwpApplication\Assets", "LockScreenLogo.*.png" ) )
{
    using( ImageMagick.MagickImage TheImage = new ImageMagick.MagickImage( ThisFile ) )
    {
        ImageMagick.PixelCollection Pixels = TheImage.GetPixels();

        for( int IX = 0; IX < TheImage.Width; IX++ )
        {
            for( int IY = 0; IY < TheImage.Height; IY++ )
            {
                Pixels[ IX, IY ].SetChannel( 0, 255 );
                Pixels[ IX, IY ].SetChannel( 1, 255 );
                Pixels[ IX, IY ].SetChannel( 2, 255 );
            }
        }

        TheImage.Write( ThisFile );
    }
}
```

Enjoy
-Simon

Answer (score 0):

Possible option (worked for me) remove:

**`<uap:LockScreen Notification="badgeAndTileText" BadgeLogo="" />`**

from Package.appxmanifest file (as xml)

If the app has nothing to do with LockScreen notifications, this seems to be an option.