# Windows Phone App Certification Kit - App manifest resources test error

Tags: image, windows-phone-8.1

## **App manifest resources test**

---

**FAILED**

- **Error Found:** The app resources validation test detected the following errors:

  `=> Image reference "Assets\BadgeLogo.png": The image "Assets\BadgeLogo.scale-240.png" has an ABGR value "0x41493F00" at position (5, 0) that is not valid. The pixel must be white (##FFFFFF) or transparent (00######).
  => Image reference "Assets\BadgeLogo.png": The image "C:\WINDOWS\temp\appcert_122C\429031395C6.AlarmSIM_1.1.0.0_neutral_split.scale-100_qw59qp28q1z3y\Assets\BadgeLogo.scale-100.png" has an ABGR value "0x28463900" at position (0, 0) that is not valid. The pixel must be white (##FFFFFF) or transparent (00######).
  => Image reference "Assets\BadgeLogo.png": The image "Assets\BadgeLogo.scale-240.png" has an ABGR value "0x41493F00" at position (5, 0) that is not valid. The pixel must be white (##FFFFFF) or transparent (00######).`
- **Impact if not fixed:** The app might not install if the strings or images declared in your app’s manifest are incorrect. If the app does install with these errors, your app’s logo or other images used by your app might not display correctly.
- **How to fix:** Fix the problem indicated by the error message. See the link below for more information: [AppX Resource Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694075.aspx)

I have tried with different tools to generate different app logos sizes but the "Windows app ceritfication kit" throws  the same error, the other validations are passed successfully.

Is there any tool or Technic that helps to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you check the `ARGB` value of the mentioned positions? The error message indicates the edge of the badge logos *must* be white (0xFFFFFFFF) or transparent (0x00FFFFFF).

Use an editing tool like [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net) to edit the badge logos, it has good support for transparency.

Comment: Thanks, can you please help to verify my logo. it is available on http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=8ec1266

Comment: looks good, the four corners are transparent, can it pass the AppX Resource Validation?

Comment: No, Please reffer: http://expirebox.com/download/668da10470be1ce6323afe67ec8e0d49.html for full information, Thanks for your quick response

Comment: maybe this is not the only badge logo in your project? have you examined all the logos in the Assets folder?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the badge needs to be basically white or transparent. I know I'm just repeating but, it needs to be WHITE || TRANSPARENT. So if your apps logo was say yellow and blue, you need to assign those colors to white and transparent. If it used multiple colors you need to convert it to bi colored scheme or redesign it.
Basically like making black and white image. I believe this badge's only purpose is for the lock screen setting's menu. There are several + + + + symbols which can be selected for quick status. You choose the app and this is where the badge is actually displayed. The 3 resolutions are for different phone screen sizes. Not positive on that but that is only place I can find the use of those badges.

```
public class MakeWite
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(58,      58,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    File f = null;

    try
    {
      f = new File("C:\\Users...location...BadgeLogo.scale-  100.png");
      img = ImageIO.read(f);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);
    }

    int width = img.getWidth();
    int Height = img.getHeight();

    for(int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
    {
      for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
      {
        int p = img.getRGB(x,y);
        int A = (p>>24)&0xff;
        int R = p&0xff;
        int G = (p>>8)&0xff;
        int B = (p>>16)&0xff;


        if( R == 255 && G == 255 && B == 255)
        {
          A = 0;
          R = 0;
          G = 0;
          B = 0;
        }
        else
        {
          R = 255;
          G = 255;
          B = 255;
        }

        p = (A<<24) | (B<<16) | (G<<8) | R;
        img.setRGB(x, y, p);
      }
    }

    try
    {
      f = new File ("C:\\Users\\...outputlocatin...\\BadgeLogo.scale-   100(2).png");
      ImageIO.write(img, "png", f);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    }
    }
```

This is a simple app and perhaps caveman way of doing it, but it converts the images to white and transparent in java.

Comment: In order for this to work, the parts which are to be transparent need to be full white in rgb parts. Sorry the image I was working with was already in this context and so that is why this java program is this way.

Comment: I think the rgb parts need to be 255 for red green blue accross the board or 0 accross the board. You can not have an rgb that is not 255 or not 0. though I beleive transparency or alpha can be variable however I have not tested that. The resulting bitmap I submitted for testing had alpha of either 0 or 255. So for what I know works, rgb parts must be all 0 or all 255, alpha must be all 0 for 0 rgb or 255 for all rgb 255. That I know passes. Will test at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post.

http://vdcruijsen.net/2013/06/fixing-the-image-badgelogo-has-an-abgr-value-value-at-position-x-y-that-is-not-valid-error-in-your-windows-8-app/

It may solve your problem.

Comment: Found more references: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/ac653cdb-d7fc-48f0-8d7b-a7ad7baea705/badgelogopng-has-an-abgr-value-at-position-1-3-that-is-not-valid-the-pixel-must-be-white?forum=toolsforwinapps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581782/window-8-24x24-badge-logo-image-failing-wac-tool-test